# Eliminate copy/paste and Factor logic out of foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have two conditions that need to traverse the same data but inside the traversal the logic changes slightly for each respective condition and in different places. If it was the same place that would be easy to factor out, but what's the best approach if it's not all in the same place for every condition? I seem to run into this situation often when parsing data.

```
switch(batch.DocumentType.ImportedFileDisposition)
{
    case ImportedFileDispositionActions.Delete:                                 
        foreach (string documentMetadataFile in documentMetadataPaths)
        {
            string documentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(documentMetadataFile);
            XDocument metadata = XDocument.Load(documentMetadataFile);
            foreach (var pageElement in metadata.Root.Element("Pages").Elements("Page"))
            {
                string pageName = null;
                XAttribute attribute = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
                if (attribute != null)
                    pageName = attribute.Value;

                string pagePath = null;
                string originalPagePath = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageName))
                {
                    pagePath = IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, pageName);
                    File.Delete(pagePath);
                }
            }
            File.Delete(documentMetadataFile);
            Directory.Delete(documentPath, true);
        }
        break;
    case ImportedFileDispositionActions.Archive:
        foreach (string documentMetadataFile in documentMetadataPaths)
        {
            string documentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(documentMetadataFile);
            string baseImportDirectory = documentPath;
            string archiveDirectory = GenerateArchiveDirectory(batch, documentPath);
            XDocument metadata = XDocument.Load(documentMetadataFile);
            foreach (var pageElement in metadata.Root.Element("Pages").Elements("Page"))
            {
                string pageName = null;
                XAttribute attribute = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
                if (attribute != null)
                    pageName = attribute.Value;

                string pagePath = null;
                string originalPagePath = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageName))
                {
                    pagePath = IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, pageName);
                    string newArchivePath = IOUtility.PathCombine(archiveDirectory, pageName);
                    try
                    {
                        IOUtility.MoveFile(pagePath, newArchivePath);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            IOUtility.CopyFile(pagePath,newArchivePath, true);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new IOException("Failed to move or copy file: " + pagePath + " to archive: " + newArchivePath, ex);
                        }
                    }
                    File.Delete(pagePath);
                }
            }
            File.Delete(documentMetadataFile);
            Directory.Delete(documentPath, true);
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Usually i would use a strategy pattern, create the context but that seems overkill for this simple bit of code that i don't plan to extend and need to just check in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start by writing another method, containing what's common in both blocks; then I'd extract another method for processing a single file, and in that method I'd decide if I want to archive or just delete the file... and then I'd get annoyed with having a method that does two things and I'd extract some `MoveOrCopyToArchive` method, and try to delete the file in all cases.

But that's just easy moving stuff around and reducing redundancies.

This is more worrying:

> ```
> try
> {
>     IOUtility.MoveFile(pagePath, newArchivePath);
> }
> catch
> {
>     try
>     {
>         IOUtility.CopyFile(pagePath,newArchivePath, true);
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         throw new IOException("Failed to move or copy file: " + pagePath + " to archive: " + newArchivePath, ex);
>     }
> }
> File.Delete(pagePath);
> ```

Nested `try/catch` blocks have a funky smell, but the worrying line is the last one: what makes you think `pagePath` can be safely deleted? If something went wrong moving or copying it, my bet is on `File.Delete` throwing an exception as well - and that one will bubble up your stack, meaning `Directory.Delete` would never get called... and the entire application might just die a horrible death.

Now back to that nested `try/catch` - first you attempt to move the file, and if that fails, you try to copy it. There are several reasons for failing to move a file, several of which will also fail to copy it. I think that's a good case for cherry-picking which exceptions will warrant trying to copy, and which ones aren't worth it:

- `ArgumentNullException` is almost certainly ruled out, you're checking if `pageName` is `null` already. But I don't know what `IOUtility.PathCombine` does, and I have no garantee that `GenerateArchiveDirectory` returns a valid path either. Better safe than sorry; catching this exception means attempting to copy the same file/path is 100% certain to fail as well.
- `ArgumentException` or `NotSupportedException` would be thrown for a path containing characters invalid in a path, or for a path in an invalid format. No need to try copying that file, it's garanteed to fail anyway.
- `DirectoryNotFoundException` and `PathTooLongException` would also fail copying.
- `IOException` would be thrown if the destination file already exists, or if the source filename wouldn't be found. Clearly not worth trying to copy.
- `UnauthorizedAccessException` - ok, moving can't work, but maybe the file can be copied.

<sub>https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx</sub>

The `catch` block that doesn't specify any exception not only enters on *any* exception, without a handle on the exception object you have lost the original exception that tells you how the first operation - moving the file - failed.

Catching `System.Exception` would be over-the-top here; as shown above, you'd only really want to try a copy when an `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown - every other exception you can possibly catch there, would be caused by something that would also make the *copy* fail.

But then if *any* of these exceptions is caught, my bet is on `File.Delete` throwing the same exception.

I'll add that throwing your own `IOException` is confusing here, because the `System.IO` methods you're using *can* throw that same exception type, with a different meaning. If you really want to wrap the exception with one of your own, then you have a case for a custom exception type here - a `FileArchiveException` or something similar.

---

Why is there no `try/catch` block in the `ImportedFileDispositionActions.Delete` case?

---

I'd do it something like this:

```
if (fileDisposition == ImportedFileDispositionActions.Archive)
{
    SendToArchive(pagePath, documentMetadataFile, batch);
}

if (File.Exists(pagePath))
{
    File.Delete(pagePath);
}

//Assert.IsFalse(File.Exists(pagePath));
```

Understanding at a glance what's going on is easier if each idea reads like a sentence.

The nested `try/catch` can be avoided by extracting a method out of the `try` block:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger; // do something about exceptions!

private void SendToArchive(string path, string metadata, FooBar batch)
{
    try
    {
        var archivePath = GenerateArchiveDirectory(path, metadata, batch);
        MoveOrCopyToArchive(archivePath);
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        _logger.Info(exception);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Debug(exception);
    }
}

private void MoveOrCopyToArchive(string path)
{
    try
    {
        File.Move(path, ArchivePath);
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException exception)
    {
        _logger.Warn(exception);
        File.Copy(path, ArchivePath, true);
    }
}
```

The stack trace will contain enough information to determine if the exception was thrown moving, copy, or deleting the file; there's not enough information in your post to recommend whether exceptions should be handled, rethrown or simply bubbled up - I've made a few assumptions here.

Comment: I agree this is an excellent approach. Can you also elaborate on how you would remove the redundancy of the iteration?

Answer (score 4):

This logic is a bit confusing, and you've got an unused variable `originalPagePath`.

> ```
> string pageName = null;
> XAttribute attribute = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
> if (attribute != null)
>     pageName = attribute.Value;
>
> string pagePath = null;
> string originalPagePath = null;
> if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageName))
> {
>     pagePath = IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, pageName);
>     File.Delete(pagePath);
> }
> ```

It can be shorted to this

```
XAttribute attribute = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
if (attribute == null)
{
    continue;
}

string pageName = attribute.Value;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageName))
{
    File.Delete(IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, pageName));
}
```

Or just this

```
XAttribute attribute = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
if (attribute != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.Value))
{
    File.Delete(IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, attribute.Value));
}
```

`fileName` would be a better name for the variable `attribute`.

```
XAttribute fileName = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
if (fileName != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName.Value))
{
    File.Delete(IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, fileName.Value));
}
```

I would also suggest using the `var` keyword, if your style guide allows it.

Comment: `baseImportDirectory` isn't used either.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely smells like a [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

If condition 'A' then do code 'A'
if condition 'B' then do code 'B'

This pattern bears itself quickly when you see thigs like

```
if(foo.equals("blah")) {
   // some code
} else if(...) {
  // some code
} else if(...) {
} else if(...) {
  // some code
} else if(...) {
} else if(...) {
  // some code
} else if(...) {
```

Keep in min that these 'else if' statements are nested 'if' statements and thus represent 'and'. So, it's like. 'if not out AND not inner1 then do code inner 2'

Other example:

```
switch(blah) {
   case x:
      // code here
   break;

   case y:
      // code here
   break;
}
```

In your case, what I see is:

2 case statements with 70% common code (meaning abstract class)
2 slight but significant deltas in each switch case (screaming for polymorphism)

I am a Java developer so forgive me for giving you an answer that is in Java; you're smart I am sure and can transpose this to C#.

```
public interface FileAction {
    public String execute(String someDir, String someFile);
}

public class DeleteAction implements FileAction {
    public String execute(String someDir, String someFile) {
        // do your delete code here
    } 
}

public class ArchiveAction implements FileAction {
    public String execute(String someDir, String someFile) {
        // do your archive code here
    } 
}

Map<ImportedFileDispositionActions, FileAction> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put(ImportedFileDispositionActions.Delete, new DeleteAction());
commands.put(ImportedFileDispositionActions.Archive, new ArchiveAction());
```

Now you can reduce your code to:

```
FileAction action = commands.get(batch.DocumentType.ImportedFileDisposition);
action.execute(...,...);
```

This allows you to move the code for archive/delete outside this file and makes it much clearer.

Allows you to easily extend this code by simply implementing the interface differently (then you can even discover new ones at runtime).

You also have the fact that, because the code to execute is/are actual objects in an interable structure (a map) instead of frozen in bytes in a switch/case statement, you can actually do clever things like iterate and output everything in the map so you can expose what "commands" are available.

This is a very common theme/pattern and [I have responded to it in the past.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43075/modularize-more-efficiently-in-an-if-else-setup/43311#43311) My answer is at the bottom (and leverages the concepts of abstract enums). But if you follow the thread you can see that your situation falls right into this category.

Read [Source making](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) -- they speak right to this case.

Answer (score -1):

I refactored the code as followed. I completely removed the need for both traversals.

```
        bool importedSuccessfully = Import(settings, batch, importPath);
        if(importedSuccessfully)
        {               
            ImportedFileDispositionActions importedFileDispositionAction = batch.DocumentType.ImportedFileDisposition;

            if(importedFileDispositionAction == ImportedFileDispositionActions.None)
                return true;

            string[] documentMetadataPaths;
            if(!LoadDocumentMetadataPaths(importPath, out documentMetadataPaths))
                return false;

            foreach(string documentMetadataFile in documentMetadataPaths)
            {
                string documentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(documentMetadataFile);
                XDocument metadata = XDocument.Load(documentMetadataFile);
                foreach(var pageElement in metadata.Root.Element("Pages").Elements("Page"))
                {
                    string pageName = null;
                    XAttribute attribute = pageElement.Attribute("FileName");
                    if(attribute != null)
                        pageName = attribute.Value;

                    string pagePath = null;
                    string originalPagePath = null;
                    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageName))
                    {
                        pagePath = IOUtility.PathCombine(documentPath, pageName);                           
                        if(importedFileDispositionAction == ImportedFileDispositionActions.Archive)
                        {
                            SendToArchive(pagePath, documentMetadataFile, batch);
                        }
                        if(File.Exists(pagePath))
                        {
                            File.Delete(pagePath);
                        }
                    }
                }
                File.Delete(documentMetadataFile);
                Directory.Delete(documentPath, true);
            }
        }
        return importedSuccessfully;
    }
    private void SendToArchive(string path,string metadata, Batch batch)
    {
        try
        {
            string pageName = Path.GetFileName(path);               
            string documentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(metadata);
            var archivePath = GenerateArchiveDirectory(batch, documentPath);
            string archivedFullPathFileName = Path.Combine(archivePath, pageName);
            if(!Directory.Exists(archivePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(archivePath);
            }
            MoveOrCopyToArchive(path, archivedFullPathFileName);
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            App.CurrentApplication.Log.Log(LogLevel.Error, exception);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            App.CurrentApplication.Log.Log(LogLevel.Error, exception);
        }
    }

    private void MoveOrCopyToArchive(string source,string target)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Move(source, target);
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException exception)
        {
            App.CurrentApplication.Log.Log(LogLevel.Warning, exception);
            File.Copy(source, target, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't really appropriate on this site. Please explain what is different with your implementation and why it is better than the original.

Comment: Oops. I just noticed that you also asked the question. If your purpose was to leave this here as a "this is how the code ended up", then please say so and mark this answer as a community wiki.